# How do I close the intermediate controller in the application?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am making a prototype of an application.

When the user opens the application, he gets to the main screen, on which the button "Login", after clicking on this button, the user opens a new window with one button "SignIn", after which the user gets to the third screen.

On the third screen, there is a "SignOut" button, which, when pressed, should return to the main screen of the application.

Example picture below:

[Sample application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFGW1.png)

I suppose that when switching from the second to the third screen, the second screen should be deleted so that only the main screen and the third screen are in the application's memory, and when the SignOut button is pressed, the user removes the third screen, and he only has the main screen in memory.

How to do it right?

MARK - At the moment I am using `segue` to move from one screen to another, and `unwindSegue` to close the screen. (Also, I'm teaching that I might need a `dismiss`, but I'm not sure about that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UINavigationController`:

1. Sets your first controller as the `rootViewController` property:

With code in your AppDelegate.swift in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: your_controller_1)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

or if you use storyboard, set the entry point with your firstViewController and embeds it inside a `UINavigationController`

2. Then play with your navigationController `self.navigationController.push(...)` to navigate to your second and third screen.
3. Use the `func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?` of `UINavigationController` to go to the rootViewController which is your first controller.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Suppose I can display the second screen through the `navigationController`, but the transition from the second to the third screen is attached to the button on the second screen, what should I do in this case?

Comment: The navigation controller works with a "stack" of viewControllers. When you use `pushViewController(...)` method on your `navigationController` it will adds the pushed controller to its stack. (You can see the current controllers through `navigationController.viewControllers` property. 

When you will click on your button on the second screen, you must :
`navigationController.pushViewController(controller: your_third_controller, animated: true)`

Comment: It turns out I need to create a `NavigationController` in `FirstViewController` and add `secondViewController` and `thirdViewController` to it? I tried to do it via `setNavigationControllers()` but it didn’t work for me :-(

Comment: Please see following code (not compiling but idea is here) : https://replit.com/join/ubxqxtxpwh-anthonyrn